# How to do？I want a protocol that can only be followed by two classes

Tags: swift, protocols, where-clause

I want a `protocol` that can only be followed by two classes。(`ClassA` or `ClassB`).

```
protocol MyProtocol where Self: ClassA || ClassB {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requirement almost certainly indicates a design problem. If any piece of your system cares what is implementing the protocol, then the protocol does not capture the whole interface. For example, if at any point you use `as? ClassA`, then this is a dangerous use of protocols.

It is impossible in Swift to have a protocol that I can see but that I cannot implement. There are languages like Go where it's possible (though still not in exactly the way you describe), but it's impossible in Swift today. As @MartinR notes, the answer by J. Doe doesn't actually change anything. Outside parties can still just implement both protocols.

With that said, it's possible to achieve things very similar to what you're describing.

First, and most obviously: use access controls.

```
private protocol MyProtocol {}

public class ClassA: MyProtocol {}

public class ClassB: MyProtocol {}
```

This works if all the classes and protocol are in one file. If not, put them all in a framework and use `internal` rather than `private`. Now nothing outside this file/module can implement `MyProtocol`. The limitation is that `MyProtocol` is also can't be seen outside the file/module.

This can be resolved by lifting a struct:

```
public struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {
    private let value: MyProtocol
    public init(classA: ClassA) { value = classA }
    public init(classB: ClassB) { value = classB }
    // Methods to conform to MyProtocol by forwarding to value
}
```

With this, it's impossible to generate a `MyStruct` that is initialized with anything but a `ClassA` or `ClassB`.

Alternately, if you really literally mean "ClassA or ClassB" that's not a struct or a protocol. That's a enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case classA(ClassA)
    case classB(ClassB)
}
```